# How to display user input values on TM1637 4 Digit Seven Segment display?

Tags: c++, arduino, embedded, iot

I have some issues with TM1637 4 digit seven segment display . I need to display the 4 digit random integer value given by user into TM1637 display. [For example: I am giving 4 digit integer say 4500 as an input inside a webpage developed by me. I want this 4500 to be displayed in TM1637 rather than displaying it in the Arduino's serial monitor ] The program is working fine incase of Serial monitor. But I don't know how to display it in TM1637. I have gone through many videos and programs in browser regarding it and tried many ways of solving this issue but I am getting this particular error every time . I think I have done some minor mistakes in the program

> CODE IS GIVEN HERE

```
#include <Arduino.h>
#ifdef ESP32
  #include <WiFi.h>
  #include <AsyncTCP.h>
  #include <TM1637Display.h>
#else
  #include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
  #include <ESPAsyncTCP.h>
#endif
#include <ESPAsyncWebServer.h>

// Defining the connections pins

#define CLK 2
#define DIO 4

int inputmessage = 0;

//Creating the display object for TM1637 

TM1637Display display = TM1637Display(CLK,DIO);

//Creating an array that turns all segments ON

const uint8_t allON[] = {0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff};

//Creating an segment that turns all segments OFF

const uint8_t allOFF[] = {0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00};

AsyncWebServer server(80);

// REPLACE WITH YOUR NETWORK CREDENTIALS
const char* ssid = "picktolight";
const char* password = "123456789";

const char* PARAM_INPUT_1 = "input1";
const char* PARAM_INPUT_2 = "input2";
const char* PARAM_INPUT_3 = "input3";

// HTML web page to handle 3 input fields (input1, input2, input3)
const char index_html[] PROGMEM = R"rawliteral(
<!DOCTYPE HTML><html><head>
  <title>ESP Input Form</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  </head><body>
  <form action="/get">
    input1: <input type="text" name="input1">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
  </form><br>
  <form action="/get">
    input2: <input type="text" name="input2">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
  </form><br>
  <form action="/get">
    input3: <input type="text" name="input3">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
  </form>
</body></html>)rawliteral";

void notFound(AsyncWebServerRequest *request) {
  request->send(404, "text/plain", "Not found");
}

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  WiFi.mode(WIFI_STA);
  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);
  if (WiFi.waitForConnectResult() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    Serial.println("WiFi Failed!");
    return;
  }
  Serial.println();
  Serial.print("IP Address: ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());

   //Setting brightness level of TM1637 display (0=dimmest, 7=brightest )
  display.setBrightness(5);

  //Setting all segments ON
  display.setSegments(allON);

  // Send web page with input fields to client
  server.on("/", HTTP_GET, [](AsyncWebServerRequest *request){
    request->send_P(200, "text/html", index_html);
  });

  // Send a GET request to <ESP_IP>/get?input1=<inputMessage>
  server.on("/get", HTTP_GET, [] (AsyncWebServerRequest *request) {
    String inputMessage;
    String inputParam;
    // GET input1 value on <ESP_IP>/get?input1=<inputMessage>
    if (request->hasParam(PARAM_INPUT_1)) {
      inputMessage = request->getParam(PARAM_INPUT_1)->value();
      inputParam = PARAM_INPUT_1;
    }
    // GET input2 value on <ESP_IP>/get?input2=<inputMessage>
    else if (request->hasParam(PARAM_INPUT_2)) {
      inputMessage = request->getParam(PARAM_INPUT_2)->value();
      inputParam = PARAM_INPUT_2;
    }
    // GET input3 value on <ESP_IP>/get?input3=<inputMessage>
    else if (request->hasParam(PARAM_INPUT_3)) {
      inputMessage = request->getParam(PARAM_INPUT_3)->value();
      inputParam = PARAM_INPUT_3;
    }
    else {
      inputMessage = "No message sent";
      inputParam = "none";
    }
    display.showNumberDec(inputMessage);
    request->send(200, "text/html", "HTTP GET request sent to your ESP on input field (" 
                                     + inputParam + ") with value: " + inputMessage +
                                     "<br><a href=\"/\">Return to Home Page</a>");
  });
  server.onNotFound(notFound);
  server.begin();
}

void loop() {

 
  
  
}
```

> ERROR

```
Arduino: 1.8.9 (Windows 10), Board: "ESP32 Dev Module, Disabled, Default 4MB with spiffs (1.2MB APP/1.5MB SPIFFS), 240MHz (WiFi/BT), QIO, 80MHz, 4MB (32Mb), 921600, None"

WARNING: Spurious .devcontainer folder in 'ArduinoJson' library
C:\Users\RD 1\Desktop\SYSTEM1\Arduino programs\ESP32 Programs\TM1637_display_trial\TM1637_display_trial.ino: In lambda function:

TM1637_display_trial:111:39: error: no matching function for call to 'TM1637Display::showNumberDec(String&)'

     display.showNumberDec(inputMessage);

                                       ^

In file included from C:\Users\RD 1\Desktop\ABISHEEK\Arduino programs\ESP32 Programs\TM1637_display_trial\TM1637_display_trial.ino:5:0:

C:\Users\RD 1\Documents\Arduino\libraries\TM1637-master/TM1637Display.h:82:8: note: candidate: void TM1637Display::showNumberDec(int, bool, uint8_t, uint8_t)

   void showNumberDec(int num, bool leading_zero = false, uint8_t length = 4, uint8_t pos = 0);

        ^

C:\Users\RD 1\Documents\Arduino\libraries\TM1637-master/TM1637Display.h:82:8: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'String' to 'int'

Multiple libraries were found for "WiFi.h"
 Used: C:\Users\RD 1\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp32\hardware\esp32\1.0.6\libraries\WiFi
 Not used: C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\libraries\WiFi
exit status 1
no matching function for call to 'TM1637Display::showNumberDec(String&)'

This report would have more information with
"Show verbose output during compilation"
option enabled in File -> Preferences.
```

I tried web socket programming in arduino. Can anyone help me in solving this please...

Comment: write a simple sketch to experiment only with the display (next time do it before asking here)

Comment: `showNumberDec` expects a number but you're passing a string

Answer (score 0):

You need:

```
display.showNumberDec( inputMessage.toInt() ) ;
//                                 ^^^^^^^^
```

You have a *global*

> ```
> int inputmessage = 0;
> ```

which is unused, and later shadowed by a local

> ```
> String inputMessage;
> ```

Then the error message is very specific:

> ```
> no matching function for call to 'TM1637Display::showNumberDec(String&)'
> ```

There is no overload of `TM1637Display::showNumberDec()` that takes a `String&` argument.  From https://github.com/avishorp/TM1637/blob/master/TM1637Display.h:

```c++
  //! @param num The number to be shown
  //! @param dots Dot/Colon enable. The argument is a bitmask, with each bit corresponding to a dot
  //!        between the digits (or colon mark, as implemented by each module). i.e.
  //!        For displays with dots between each digit:
  //!        * 0.000 (0b10000000)
  //!        * 00.00 (0b01000000)
  //!        * 000.0 (0b00100000)
  //!        * 0.0.0.0 (0b11100000)
  //!        For displays with just a colon:
  //!        * 00:00 (0b01000000)
  //!        For displays with dots and colons colon:
  //!        * 0.0:0.0 (0b11100000)
  //! @param leading_zero When true, leading zeros are displayed. Otherwise unnecessary digits are
  //!        blank. NOTE: leading zero is not supported with negative numbers.
  //! @param length The number of digits to set. The user must ensure that the number to be shown
  //!        fits to the number of digits requested (for example, if two digits are to be displayed,
  //!        the number must be between 0 to 99)
  //! @param pos The position of the most significant digit (0 - leftmost, 3 - rightmost)
  void showNumberDecEx(int num, uint8_t dots = 0, bool leading_zero = false, uint8_t length = 4, uint8_t pos = 0);
```

Answer (score -1):

The output to the display is done only once in setup()!
Does it work to write any number is you do in in the loop()?
Is there some text to display? Put the 'inputMessage' to Serial.

```
loop() {
   display.showNumberDec( 4711 );
   
}
```

Comment: Judging by the error message `showNumberDec` takes an integer so your code won't work